# .NET COM Dll passing byte[] by reference

Tags: .net, silverlight, dll, com, byref

I have a COM dll that I have created in .NET. I am accessing it via silverlight. The issue I am having is that I am passing a byte[] to the COM dll but it does not seem to work properly. I have tried marking it as [In][Out] with no luck.

```
void LoadData(byte[] data)
```

This is what my function looks like. It loads the data fine on the COM side but it doesn't make it back to silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the array by reference when using COM Interop:

```
void LoadData(ref byte[] data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to study the default marshaling for arrays [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6.aspx).

If that doesn't help you, generate a type library for your COM dll (e.g. using tlbexp).  When you see the IDL definition of the function you're calling it may become obvious to you why your byte[] parameter isn't working.  If it's still not clear, post that IDL here and it will at least give us more clues.

Answer (score -2):

```
byte[] data = new byte[30]
LoadData(Convert.toBase64String(data.Tostring()));


void LoadData(byte[] data)
{

}
```

Comment: `LoadData` takes a byte array as input - you're trying to pass it a string. How does this address the problem?

Comment: Convert.toBase64String() returns byte[]

Comment: No it doesn't! It's called **To** Base64 **String** for a reason -  [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx). You may be thinking of `Convert.FromBase64String`, but that still doesn't address the problem.